# Why doesn't the ":last-child" selector work for me?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In my application, I run an array of objects in my html to display the information of 3 different types of services, and at the end of the info I want to show a vertical bar that will act as a separator.

```
                <div class="column-service-container">
                  <div
                    class="column-service"
                    v-for="order in filteredOrder"
                    v-bind:key="order.name"
                    :class="{ focusService: order.name == focusService }"
                    @click="focusService = order.name"
                    v-on:click="getOrder()"
                  >
                  <div class="column-service-wrapper">
                    <div class="column-service-text">
                      <div class="item-service-name">{{order.name}}</div>
                      <div class="item-service-description">{{order.full_description}}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-service-price">
                      {{order.itc.toString().replace(".", ",") }}
                      <span class="price-currency">€</span>
                      <span class="ttc-desc">TTC*</span>
                      <input
                        ref="service"
                        type="radio"
                        name="selectedOrderService"
                        v-model="selectedOrderService"
                        :value="order.name"
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="vert-sep"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

As you can see below in css, I place the info in columns with the separator bar on the right. The problem arises when I want to hide the bar that corresponds to the last column.
I tried with the "last:child" selector, as you can see below, but it doesn't work.
In this case it hides the 3 bars with that class.

```
.column-service-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.column-service {
 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.column-service-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

div.vert-sep {
  width: 4px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: -2px;
  background: $secondaryColor;
}

.vert-sep:last-child {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.column-service:last-child .vert-sep` ? I'm not sure about the base element of your columns.

Comment: thank you!!! I've been blocked for a while and I couldn't see why it didn't apply!

Comment: You're welcome. `.vert-sep` is always the `last-child` of it's parent, that's why your selector was incorrect and why you have to select `.vert-sep` inside the last column.

Comment: @AmauryHanser If you put your explanation in response I will mark it as accepted. Thanks for everything

Comment: Thanks, I'm note sure it deserves to be an answer. I'm just happy it worked for you, happy coding. ;-)